# Neo4j, Cypher merge query does not execute with REST API

Tags: rest, neo4j, asp.net-web-api

I want to use REST API (.NET) and to issue a merge query to execute for neo4j database. My query is:

```
{ "query" : "MERGE  (n:Person { props } ) ON CREATE SET n.id = 55 RETURN n" , "params" :{  "props" : { "name" : 'Mahsa', "lastname" : 'Hassankashi' }  }}
```

OR

```
{ "query" : "MERGE  (n:Person { props } ) ON CREATE SET n.id = {PersonID}  RETURN n" , "params" :{  "props" : { "name" : 'Mahsa' }   , "PersonID" : 55} }
```

But my "HttpWebResponse response" is null and when HttpWebResponse returns null because when I send it to stream it at this line:

```
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

It has Length and position error:

(1): 'requestStream.Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

(2). "This stream does not support seek operations.", it means my query is not proper. How can I correct query.

It is important that I have answer from my httpwebresponse for other cypher query, it means that my sending request(cypher) and receiving response is possible by other queries.

Below Query works when I put it directly on neo4j 2.2.4:

```
MERGE  (n:Person { name : "mahsa", lastname : "hassankashi" } ) ON CREATE SET n.id=55 RETURN n
```

Request Class:

```
//****** Send Cypher Query by HttpWebRequest and Stream
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            request.Method = methodType;
            request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;


            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Thank you in advanced for help.

Comment: Maybe you can share code sample, where request is constructed?

Comment: @FylmTM , I wrote request class but it works correctly for other cypher queries.

Comment: Do you have a uniqueness constraint that involves the `Person` label?

Comment: For `MERGE` you have to send individual parameters (values) for each property, something like `MERGE (n:Person {name: {name}, lastname: {lastname}})` and `"params":{"name":"mahsa","lastname":"hassankashi"}`. Or unpack the single parameter map in the query.

Comment: @jjaderberg I tested so many times but I just could get answer without parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Cypher Transnational Endpoint without using parameters, when I am using parameters I cannot use Merge with REST API.

```
{"statements" : [ {"statement" : "MERGE (n:Person { name : 'Mahsa' , lastname : 'Hassankashi' } ) ON CREATE SET n.id =1 RETURN n"} ]}
```

POST to : http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that you use invalid JSON format for [Cypher transactional endppoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html)

In your case this should be something like this:

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "MERGE  (n:Person { props } ) ON CREATE SET n.id = 55 RETURN n",
    "parameters" : {
      "props" : {
        "name" : 'Mahsa', 
        "lastname" : 'Hassankashi'
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

This will be correct JSON input for transaction endpoint.

If you use some specific .NET library for making calls to Neo4j database - you should verify your input against their documentation.